# FooTable Stop pagination start by default

Tags: jquery, pagination, footable

How can I stop pagination plugins, I want single page with sorting but no pagination. I search on google but no hope (maybe wrong keyword), please help

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$('.footable').footable({paginate: false});

Should work.
If you have any other issues you can find the documentation in the demos folder of the V2 branch on the footable git repo.

http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/